# error in sqlite database when loaded in php

Tags: sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLite database path not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261107/sqlite-database-path-not-working)

```
D:/wamp/www/umer.db
Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: no such table: config in
    D:\wamp\www\sqllite\index.php on line 15
Error in query: SQL logic error or missing database
```

I found this error when loaded data base in PHP. My source code is this:

```
<?php
    $db = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."umer.db";  
    echo $db;

    $handle = sqlite_open($db) or
        die("Could not open database".sqlite_error_string(sqlite_last_error($handle)));
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM config");

    $result = sqlite_query($handle,$query) or
        die("Error in query: ".sqlite_error_string(sqlite_last_error($handle)));
    if (sqlite_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=1>";
        while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    sqlite_close($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . 'umer.db'`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it *looks* like you don't have a `config` table:

```
D:/wamp/www/umer.db Warning: sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]:
    no such table: config in   <<<<< SEE HERE!
        D:\wamp\www\sqllite\index.php on line 15
            Error in query: SQL logic error or missing database
```

Are you sure that table exists?

It seems to be opening the database okay since the first error occurs on the `sqlite_query()` call.

Comment: yes it sur that the table is existing but the error msg is again it shows....what should to do for testing it ?