# error in SQLite database when using with php

Tags: sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLite database path not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261107/sqlite-database-path-not-working)

```
sqlite_query() [function.sqlite-query]: no such table: friends in D:\wamp\www\sqllite\index.php on line 11
```

Error in query: SQL logic error or missing database

```
i am facing with this error. the data base ios connected correct.but it shows that no table
my source code of php is this 

$db = "testdb.db";  

echo $db;
$handle = sqlite_open($db) or die("Could not open database".sqlite_error_string(sqlite_last_error($handle)));

$query = ("SELECT * FROM friends");
$result = sqlite_query($handle,$query) or die("Error in query: ".sqlite_error_string(sqlite_last_error($handle)));
if (sqlite_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row[0];
        echo $row[1];
        echo $row[2];
    }
}


sqlite_close($handle);
?>
```

and the my databas file source code is this its name is testdb.db

```
$dbhandle = sqlite_open('db/test.db', 0666, $error);
if (!$dbhandle) die ($error);

$stm = "CREATE TABLE Friends(Id integer PRIMARY KEY," . 
       "Name text UNIQUE NOT NULL, Sex text CHECK(Sex IN ('M', 'F')))";
$ok = sqlite_exec($dbhandle, $stm, $error);

if (!$ok)
   die("Cannot execute query. $error");

echo "Database Friends created successfully";

sqlite_close($dbhandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

table friends != Friends

check it :-)